# TCP client/server program between ubuntu and raspberry pi

Tags: c, ubuntu, tcp, raspberry-pi

I want to do the TCP client/server communication between `Raspberry Pi` and laptop with `Ubuntu` OS running using `VMware Workstation`. Raspberry Pi act as the client and Ubuntu act as the server. I am able to successfully compile the client and server program.But on the client side it throws an error `ERROR, no such host`. I made changes in Ubuntu network settings to share with other computers. But still communication is not taking place. I am able to ping successfully between Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu. But I am not able to communicate between the client and server side. Can anyone solve this issue and suggest me how to do the network settings in Ubuntu so that Pi and Ubuntu can communicate.

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
        (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
        server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;
    if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        portno = atoi(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
        sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR on accept");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
    n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
    if (n < 0)
        error("ERROR writing to socket");
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: When you start client on RPi, what do you pass as first argument: hostname or IP address?

Comment: I pass the hostname as first argument and then port no. Eg: ./client ubuntu 2001

Comment: 'ubuntu' is not (normally) a valid hostname.  I would suggest doing a `netstat` in the VM to get the IP address and passing that to the client.

Comment: to avoid problems, do not cast the parameters to `bcopy()` and `bzero()`

Comment: when calling `fgets()` pass the full size of the input buffer, because the `fgets()` function will properly terminate the buffer, within the past-in size.

Comment: always check the returned value from `fgets()` to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the client seems to be missing the `bind()` statement that connects the port and the socket.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans, 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) when coding, separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a single blank line

Comment: the client code probably wants something similar to: `on = 1;
    sockoptstatus = setsockopt( sock_in, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on) );
    if ( -1 == sockoptstatus ) ...` so more than one message can be sent//received over that connection.